# How to serve html files without re-creating container every time?

Tags: docker

I think this should be a simple one. I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/serve-static-files-from-docker-via-nginx-basic-example-arun-kumar):

my current dir on mac is `/var/www/html/test/testme/misc/docker-static/web`

How do I serve the html files within without re-create the container every time?

```
#
# BudgetTracker Dockerfile for UI
#
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Arunkumar Srisailapathi "sail.arunkumar@gmail.com"

USER root

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx nodejs

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ADD web /usr/share/nginx/html/
ADD web /var/www/html/

# Append "daemon off;" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 90

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

Comment: If you mean don't restart container after file changes, use `volume`, not `Add`.

Comment: OK. good idea..